# Error : Can't connect to Mysql server on '' (10055)

Tags: c++, mysql

Some times my appplication gives the following error. I do not understrand why this error occures . 
My server database  on windows machine. My server works perfectly with INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE for mysql.
After process~29000 files my application crash!

Answer (score 0):

the relation between code and DB is based on a connections whose using ports on both sides client/server
that's why is totally recommended to close the connections after using it, because the exceed of opened port will block the connection wich will be the cause of launching such exception

Comment: you just call the close() method of the connection object

Comment: i used that.. you can see  my answer!

Comment: try this code ! MYSQL *connect; 
    connect=mysql_init(NULL);
    
    if(!connect) 
    { 
        return 1;
    } 
    connect=mysql_real_connect(connect,SERVER,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE,0,NULL,0);

    if(connect){
        cout<<"Connection Succeeded\n";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Connection Failed!\n");
    }
    MYSQL_RES *res_set;
    MYSQL_ROW row; 
    mysql_query(connect,"SELECT * FROM TABLE");
 /*instructions*/
    mysql_close(connect);

Comment: i see what do you mean. in my code, i open the connection just when my application started with MySQLConnection->Close();
   MySQLConnection->Params->Values["Database"] = ExtractFileName(TOpenProjectForm1->ProjectNameEdit->Text);
   MySQLConnection->Params->Values["User_Name"] = TOpenProjectForm1->UsernameEdit->Text;
   MySQLConnection->Params->Values["Password"] =  TOpenProjectForm1->PasswordEdit->Text;
   MySQLConnection->Params->Values["HostName"] =  TOpenProjectForm1->HostNameEdit->Text;

Comment: and i use that to execute my query :                    TSQLQuery* ExtractMetaSQLQuery = new TSQLQuery(NULL); 
           ExtractMetaSQLQuery->SQLConnection =  MySQLConnection;
           ExtractMetaSQLQuery->SQL->Add(sql1);
           ExtractMetaSQLQuery->ExecSQL(true);
           ExtractMetaSQLQuery->Close();

Comment: why using T-SQL when it s a mysql db ?

Comment: my application is VCL form with Rad Studio.. i used the dbexpress to connect my database  [dbexpress](http://conferences.embarcadero.com/article/32229)